# Operator override - when to use friend?

Tags: c++, friend

I'm wondering why the () operator override can't be "friend" (and so it needs a "this" additional parameter) while the + operator needs to be friend like in the following example:

```
class fnobj
{
    int operator()(int i);
    friend int operator+(fnobj& e);
};

int fnobj::operator()(int i)
{

}

int operator+(fnobj& e)
{

}
```

I understood that the + operator needs to be friend to avoid the "additional" extra *this* parameter, but why is that the operator() doesn't need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have overloaded the *unary plus* operator.  And you probably didn't want to do that.  It does not add two objects, it describes how to interpret a single object when a `+` appears before it, the same as `int x = +10` would be interpreted.  (It's interpreted the same as `int x = 10`)

For the **addition operator**, it is not correct that "the + operator needs to be friend".

Here are two ways to add two `fnobj` objects:

```
int operator+(fnobj& e);
friend int operator+(fnobj& left, fnobj& right);
```

In the first form, `this` is presumed to be the object to the left of the `+`.  So both forms effectively take two parameters.

**So to answer your question**, instead of thinking that "operator() doesn't need `friend`", consider it as "operator() requires `this`"  Or better still, "Treating an object as a function requires an object".

Comment: Thank you, and the () operator is called on a single object so must necessarily be a member function, is that correct?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Correct.  I've edited my answer to illuminate that.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling if you do some searching (or asking here) you can learn how the `friend` form of addition is preferred, for one particular reason.

Comment: Why is that Drew? I'm interested

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Hit the ask question button. Don't assume that I can give you the best answer. I don't. :)

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765186/c-operator-override-why-is-it-friend-preferred

Answer (score 2):

You didn't understand this correctly (and aren't using it correctly as well).

There are two ways in C++ to define a binary operator for a class, either as a member function

```
class A
{
public:
    int operator+ (A const& other);
};
```

or as a free function

```
class A {};

int operator+ (A const& lhs, A const& rhs);
```

What you are currently mixing up is that you can declare and define this free function in the class scope as `friend`, which will allow the function to use private members of the class (which is not allowed in general for free functions).