# C++ operator override - why is it friend preferred?

Tags: c++

Continuing from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764696/operator-override-when-to-use-friend/12764769#comment17250263_12764769) I'd like to ask why the "friend" form of addition in a C++ operator override is preferred

To summarize:

for the addition operator override there are two ways to do it:

```
int operator+(Object& e);
friend int operator+(Object& left, Object& right);
```

why is that the second (friend) form is preferred? What are the advantages?

Comment: Probably better to quote the relevant bits from the last question, so people don't have to click through to it (and also in case the question disappears)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-member version (friend or otherwise) is preferred because it can support implicit conversions on both the left and right side of the operator.

Given a type that is implicitly convertible to Object:

```
struct Widget
{
  operator Object() const;
};
```

Only the non-member version can be called if an instance of `Widget` appears on the left-hand side:

```
Widget w;
Object o;

o + w; // can call Object::operator+( Object & ) since left-hand side is Object
w + o; // can only call operator+( Object &, Object & )
```

---

In response to your comment:

By defining the conversion operator in `Widget`, we are notifying the compiler that instances of `Widget` can be automatically converted to instances of `Object`.

```
Widget w;
Object o = w;  // conversion
```

In the expression `o + w`, the compiler calls `Object::operator+( Object & )` with an argument generated by converting `w` to an `Object`.  So the result is the same as writing `o + w.operator Object()`.

But in the expression `w + o`, the compiler looks for `Widget::operator+` (which doesn't exist) or a non-member `operator+( Widget, Object )`.  The latter can be called by converting `w` to an `Object` as above.

Comment: I don't quite understand the widget/object struct code, can you please provide a simple and extremely short example?

Answer (score 2):

The rule is not universal: the `friend` version is preferred when you implement a logically symmetric operation that takes two arguments of the same type, such as the case that your post demonstrates.

This implementation underscores the fact that the operation is truly symmetric: it's not a 'Object this' that adds `Object e` to itself - rather, that's an addition of `lhs` and `rhs`.

In situations when the operation is non-symmetric - for example, when you add an `int` to an iterator, you should prefer the first way of implementing operators, namely

```
Object& operator+(int& offset);
```